# Parametrization of circle in clockwise

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, circles, parametrization

How to parametrize a circle in a clockwise direction? The problem was "$C$ is the portion of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$ traced clockwise."

What I did was $c(t) = (\cos t, -\sin t)$, $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ but I don't know if it's correct. What does this look like when sketched?

Comment: This is the WHOLE unit circle traced clockwise starting from $(1,0)$. Select a suitable subinterval of $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: should it be $[0, \frac {\pi}{2}]$?

Comment: What is $c(0)$? What is $c(\pi/2)$? Note that $c(0)=c(2\pi)$

Comment: c(t)=(sin(t),cos(t)) can work in this case.

Comment: @Alv with $[0, \frac {\pi}{2}]$ or $[\frac{-\pi}{2}, 0]$ ?

Comment: @mamab yes it works for[0,$\frac{\pi}{2}$].